# How to load data dinnamicaly inside ViewPager fragment from database

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm aiming to create app that having swipe gesture to switch between products. At first, i create app with navigation drawer. this drawer item/menu will load different fragment.

in this particular fragment, named coupon, i want to implement the viewpager. this is what i achieve on my try:

1. create coupon fragment which loaded when i click one of item in navigation drawer
2. on CouponFragment.java i put:

   ```
   mCustomPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), getActivity());

   mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
   mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);
   ```
3. on fragment_coupon.xml i put the ViewPager
4. I Create CustomPagerAdapter that extends FragmentPagerAdapter:

   public class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

   ```
   protected Context mContext;

   public CustomPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
       super(fm);
       mContext = context;
   }

   @Override
   // This method returns the fragment associated with
   // the specified position.
   //
   // It is called when the Adapter needs a fragment
   // and it does not exists.
   public Fragment getItem(int position) {

       // Create fragment object
       Fragment fragment = new DemoFragment();

       // Attach some data to it that we'll
       // use to populate our fragment layouts
       Bundle args = new Bundle();
       args.putInt("page_position", position + 1);
       args.putString("coupon_name", "Promo Lorem Ipsum");
       args.putString("coupon_desc", "description is here");

       // Set the arguments on the fragment
       // that will be fetched in DemoFragment@onCreateView
       fragment.setArguments(args);

       return fragment;
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       return 3;
   }
   ```

   }
5. I create DemoFragment.java which loaded inside adapter:

   public class DemoFragment extends Fragment {

   ```
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // Inflate the layout resource that'll be returned
       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_demo, container, false);

       // Get the arguments that was supplied when
       // the fragment was instantiated in the
       // CustomPagerAdapter
       Bundle args = getArguments();
       ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("Page " + args.getInt("page_position"));
       ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.test1)).setText("" + args.getString("coupon_name"));
       ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.test2)).setText("" + args.getString("coupon_desc"));
       return rootView;
   }
   ```

   }
6. I create fragment_demo.xml:

   ```
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:text="Page 0"
       android:id="@+id/text" />

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/test1"/>
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/test2"/>
   ```

**my question:**

2. I want to load bunch of products there, let say like 20 products to swipe. how can i do that? i only got position, but not the product id to load the data

Comment: On what basis you wan product data to be loaded, ie from what i understand, get those 20 product form the database  and pass it to adapter??

Comment: @VikasRathod What function i can use? on getItem, i only load 1 record at a time, right?

Comment: get all the 20 product once form the  database and pass a list inside CustomPagerAdapter(List<Product> list,...); and in getCount() return list.size

Comment: Not sure i understand how it works, but I will try it first. thanks!

Comment: @VikasRathod its works! Thanks!

Comment: @VikasRathod how can i accept comment as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all the 20 product once form the database and pass a list inside CustomPagerAdapter(List list,...); and in getCount() return list.size